# Two inequalities with exponential function

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, exponential-function

I am interested in seeing proofs for the following two statements:
1.)
$\forall x\in \mathbb{C}, |x|\le 1:$
$$|\operatorname{exp}(x)-1|\leq\tfrac{|x|}{1-|x|}$$

2.)
$\forall x\in \mathbb{C}, |x|\leq \tfrac{1}{2}:$
$$|\operatorname{exp}(x)-1-x|\leq |x|^2$$

Maybe one can show the second one with the help of the first one?

Comment: For 1.) one can use the power series expansion of $\exp$ and the geometric series (and for 2.) as well)

Comment: This is not a "do my homework" site, sorry! *Of course*, you're interested in others doing your work.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I ask for hints, not for solutions and those are not homework but statements in books I read, used for other proofs, if you believe me or not.

Comment: According to the rules of this place, information about the origin of a problem and your motivation to solve it (also known as "context") should be contained *in your question* (believe me or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To follow leoli1's comment,) note that for $|z|\le 1$:
$$
|e^z-1|\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!}\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty|z|^n=\frac{|z|}{1-|z|}
$$

and for $|z|\le\frac12$:
$$
{|e^z-1-z|}
\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{|z|^n}{n!}
\le \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac12|{z}|^n=\frac{|z|^2}{2(1-|z|)}\le|z|^2
$$